# How to enable a LineEdit when a CheckBox is checked

Tags: python, pyside

I need to make a macro in Python.

I want to enable a `QlineEdit` when a `QCheckBox` is checked; how do I do it?

This is the code:

```
import os, sys, App
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *

class Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.fabricatorLineEdit = self.createLineEdit("fabricatorLineEdit", "fabricator")
        self.fabricatorLineEdit.setDisabled(True)

        self.chBoxFab = self.createCheckBox("chBoxFab", "Insert a alternative value to 'fabricator' key:")
        self.chBoxFab.stateChanged.connect(self.chbxStateChange(self.chBoxFab, self.fabricatorLineEdit))

        self.chBoxPrjManager = self.createCheckBox("chBoxPrjManager", "Insert a alternative value to 'Project Manager' key:")

        self.projManagerLineEdit = self.createLineEdit("projManagerLineEdit", "Project Manager")
        self.projManagerLineEdit.setDisabled(True)  
      self.chBoxPrjManager.stateChanged.connect(self.chbxStateChange(self.chBoxPrjManager , self.projManagerLineEdit))
        mainLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
        mainLayout.addRow(self.chBoxFab)
        mainLayout.addRow(self.fabricatorLineEdit)
        mainLayout.addRow(self.chBoxPrjManager)
        mainLayout.addRow(self.projManagerLineEdit)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

    def createLineEdit(self, objName, defaultTxt):
        lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        lineEdit.setObjectName(objName)
        lineEdit.setText(defaultTxt)
        return lineEdit

    def createCheckBox(self, objName, objCaption):
        chBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self)
        chBox.setObjectName(objName)
        chBox.setText(objCaption)
        return chBox

    def chbxStateChange(self, chBox, lineEdit):
       if chBox.isChecked:
        lineEdit.setDisabled(False)
       else:
          lineEdit.setDisabled(True)

    if __name__ == '__main__':

       import sys

       window = Window()
       result = window.exec_()
```

I define an event to check the state of the `QCheckBox` to enable the `QlineEdit` but it doesn't work:

```
    def chbxStateChange(self, chBox, lineEdit):
        if chBox.isChecked:
            lineEdit.setDisabled(False)
        else:
            lineEdit.setDisabled(True)
```

I understand that the problem is in the function `chbxStateChange` but I don't know how to resolve it.

The error:

> error return without exception set
>   Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Program
>   Files/.../Python/Scripts/test.py", line 332, in 
>               window = Window() File "C:/Program Files/.../Python/Scripts/test.py", line 35, in **init**
>
> self.chBoxFab.stateChanged.connect(self.chbxStateChange(self.chBoxFab,
>   self.fabricatorLineEdit))

Comment: Change self.chBoxFab.stateChanged.connect(self.chbxStateChange(self.chBoxFab, self.fabricatorLineEdit)) to self.chBoxFab.stateChanged.connect(self.chbxStateChange(lambda: self.chBoxFab, self.fabricatorLineEdit))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors in your code.

Firstly, the `connect` method of signals takes a *callable object*, but your code passes in the *return value* of a method (which in this case is `None`). So instead, you should make the connections like this:

```
self.chBoxFab.stateChanged.connect(
    lambda: self.chbxStateChange(self.chBoxFab,
                                 self.fabricatorLineEdit))

self.chBoxPrjManager.stateChanged.connect(
    lambda: self.chbxStateChange(self.chBoxPrjManager,
                                 self.projManagerLineEdit))
```

Secondly, the `chbxStateChange` method makes the opposite mistake of treating `isChecked` as an attribute (rather than calling it), meaning it will always evaluate to `True`. So instead, the code should look like this:

```
def chbxStateChange(self, chBox, lineEdit):
    if chBox.isChecked():
        lineEdit.setDisabled(False)
    else:
        lineEdit.setDisabled(True)
```

However, if all you want to do is toggle the enabled state of a line-edit, this code is overcomplicated. The connections can instead be made like this:

```
self.chBoxFab.toggled.connect(self.fabricatorLineEdit.setEnabled)
self.chBoxPrjManager.toggled.connect(self.projManagerLineEdit.setEnabled)
```

The [toggled signal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#toggled) sends the button's checked state (`True` or `False`) which can then directly set the enabled state of the line-edit. (And If you wanted to the line-edit to be *disabled* when the button is checked, you would connect `toggled` to `setDisabled`).

If you do things this way, the `chbxStateChange` method is no longer needed.

---

(NB: the [QCheckBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcheckbox.html) class inherits [QAbstractButton](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html), which is where it gets the `toggled` signal from).

Comment: Thank you for the advises and above all for your time.